# PHP array_diff_uassoc() Function

Tags: php

I just started learning PHP from w3schools.
The code that is given below is sending three arrays to a function named `myfunction`.

```
$result=array_diff_uassoc($a1,$a2,$a3,"myfunction");
```

But the Function is accepting only two arrays.

```
function myfunction($a,$b)
```

What is this?

The [complete code link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_diff_uassoc2)

Comment: Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: @JohnConde: I'm no w3schools fanboy, but they have cleaned up their act. Even w3fools acknowledge this. Their site explicitly states that it is a decent enough place to start

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I think the PHP manual is a better place to start.

Comment: @JohnConde: Yes, it is. But it lacks the tutorial structure that beginners do need... That's why using w3schools is ok _at first_. Once you can write some actual code, turn to php.net, or another source

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem really they have not done any of that... [XSS vulnerbility 1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp). [XSS vulnerability 2](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Comment: @peehaa One of the pages you said, mentions security and the next page mentions XSS specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the docs for [array_diff_uassoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php) to view what the callback definition is, this is the method it uses to perform the comparison and it accepts two values, despite the number of values provided:

**Parameter: key_compare_func**

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

```
int callback ( mixed $a, mixed $b )
```

The callback method in the example provided is `function myfunction($a,$b)`.

You can also see from the docs that you can provide 2 or more arrays to the function, this is noted by the following definition at the top of the page:

> array array_diff_uassoc ( array $array1 , array $array2 **[, array
>   $... ]**, callable $key_compare_func )

Comment: What is this? return ($a > $b)? 1:-1;

Comment: It means that the callback function returns a 1 or a -1 value result depending on whether the logic within the callback function deems that array $a is 'more' than array `$b`.  1 if yes, -1 if no

Comment: Feel free to vote up and accept as the answer if you deem it's appropriate! :)